# How to fix undefined 'undefined reference to ****** collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status' in C

Tags: c, arrays, visual-studio, sorting, compiler-errors

I'm trying to make a C program, but I keep getting an error from a function I added:

> undefined reference to `genName'collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

The function I added is made to generate a random name. The rest of the code worked before, but when I try to test this new function the above error occurs.

The new function is defined as (defined after all the rest of my code):

```
char* genName()
{
    srand(time(0));
    int r = rand() % (sizeof(firstNames)/sizeof(firstNames[0]));
    strcpy(first, firstNames[r]);
    int v = rand() % (sizeof(lastNames)/sizeof(lastNames[0]));
    srand(time(0));
    strcpy(last, lastNames[v]);
    strcat(first, last);
    return first;
}
```

The rest of my code is:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

// If 0, organize by all. if 1, organize by grade. if 3, organize by speed.
int method = 3;

char first[40];
char last[25];
char* genName();

typedef struct
{
    char name[60];
    int score;
    double time;
} student;

char firstNames[][15] =
{
    {"John"},
    {"Jim"},
    {"Tim"},
    {"Sam"},
    {"Jack"},
    {"Larry"},
    {"Bob"},
    {"Mack"},
    {"Kyle"},
    {"Tom"},
    {"Joe"},
    {"Dan"}
};

char lastNames[][25] =
{
    {" Howards"},
    {" Nyles"},
    {" Jones"},
    {" White"},
    {" Myles"},
    {" Simones"},
    {" Smith"},
    {" Johnson"},
    {" Williams"},
    {" Brown"},
    {" Jackson"},
    {" Martin"},
    {" Davis"},
    {" Thompson"},
    {" Moore"}
};


int compare(const void*, const void*);

student s1 = {"Jim Howards", 89, 4.90};
student s2 = {"Tim Nyles", 76, 6.12};
student s3 = {"John Jones", 97, 7.56};
student s4 = {"Sam White", 50, 1.12};
student s5 = {"Jack Myles", 88, 3.90};

int main()
{
    student array[] = {s1, s2, s3, s4, s5};
    qsort(array, (sizeof(array)/sizeof(array[0])), sizeof(array[0]), compare);

    if (method == 1)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < (sizeof(array)/sizeof(array[0])); i++)
        {
            printf("%d.%s, with a score of %d%%\n", i+1, array[i].name, array[i].score);
        }    
    }
    else
    {
        if (method == 2)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < (sizeof(array)/sizeof(array[0])); i++)
            {
                printf("%d.%s, with a time of %1.2f minutes\n", i+1, array[i].name, array[i].time);
            }    
        }
        else
        {
            if (method == 3)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < (sizeof(array)/sizeof(array[0])); i++)
                {
                    printf("%d.%s, with a score of %d%%, and a time of %1.2f\n", i+1, array[i].name, array[i].score, array[i].time);
                }
            }
        } 
    }

    char* hi = genName();
    printf("%s", hi);

    return 0;
}

int compare(const void * num1, const void * num2)
{
    student *st1 = (student *)num1;
    student *st2 = (student *)num2;
    if (method == 1)
    {
        if (st1->score < st2->score)
        {
            return 1;
        }
        if (st1->score == st2->score)
        {
            return 0;
        }
        if (st1->score > st2->score)
        {
            return -1;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if (method == 2)
        {
            if (st1->time > st2->time)
            {
                return 1;
            }
            if (st1->time == st2->time)
            {
                return 0;
            }
            if (st1->time < st2->time)
            {
                return -1;
            }   
        } 
        else
        {
            if (method == 3)
            {
                if (st1->score < st2->score)
                {
                    return 1;
                }

                if (st1->score == st2->score)
                {
                    if (st1->time > st2->time)
                    {
                        return 1;
                    }
                    if (st1->time == st2->time)
                    {
                        return 0;
                    }
                    if (st1->time < st2->time)
                    {
                        return -1;
                    }  

                }

                if (st1->score > st2->score)
                {
                    return -1;
                }   
            } 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: There are dozens of duplicates for this question on Stack Overflow. They all start from the fact that the author does not indent the code properly. You've got an IDE, it should make this easy. There is no excuse for you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As written, your implementation of `char *genName()` is inside the brackets of your implementation of `int compare(const void*, const void*)`. Consistent indentation can help avoid errors like these.